# Visual Studio: have region description be based on text within the region

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

With a method like this:

```
#region _DESCRIPTION_
[Author("A")]
[City("B")]
[Year("2009")]
#endregion
void Method() { }
```

I'd like `_DESCRIPTION_` to reflect the value of the `Author` method attribute.

Any ideas on how I could implement this? The reason is that I have many attributes, some are long, so I contain them within a region. I'd like the region description to reflect the value of one attribute in particular, automatically (otherwise I need to remember to update both each time).

I'm using VS 2010. Thanks.

Comment: OMG, I already hate regions, but you'd make me hate them even more with that sort of code.  **Also**, you're attributes are short, why not move them onto one line:  `[Author("A"), City("B"), Year("2009")]`?

Comment: Same feelings here :) These attributes were just an example, in reality the problem is that they span multiple lines each, so I want to hide them in regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is doable at language level.  #region is a preprocessor directive in C#, and C# spec does not offer this.

VisualStudio 2010 already implemented a feature that when you mouse over a collapsed block, it will show the first several lines of that block.   Otherwise the only way maybe just do this

```
#region [Author("A")]
```